Selenium python save screenshot on the Debian 11
import math
from selenium import webdriver
from fpdf import FPDF
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

url= sys.argv[1]

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
options.add_argument('--incognito')
options.add_argument('--start-maximized')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=options)
driver.get(url)

width = driver.execute_script("return Math.max( document.body.scrollWidth, document.body.offsetWidth, document.documentElement.clientWidth, document.documentElement.scrollWidth, document.documentElement.offsetWidth );")

height = driver.execute_script("return Math.max( document.body.scrollHeight, document.body.offsetHeight, document.documentElement.clientHeight, document.documentElement.scrollHeight, document.documentElement.offsetHeight );")

#driver.set_window_size(width, height)
element = driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'body')
element.screenshot("file.png")



When I tried to run the above script, it gave me an error (https://i.sstatic.net/jy76ZyQF.png)

What can I do to be able to perform such an operation on Debian 11 server version (without gui). I tested this for different systems that had a gui such as windows 10 or ubuntu 22.04, and there was no problem.

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors. This includes HTML.

always put code, data and full error message as text (not screenshot, not link) in question (not in comment).  It will be more readable and easier to use in answer (simpler to select and copy), and more people will see it - so more people can help you.

do you get the same error when you use .set_window_size()? Linux has program Xvfb to create fake X Windows to run program without displaying window (without using --headless in Chrome) and maybe it will work better. There should be even Python module to run this Xvfb - xvfbwrapper

python - How do I run Selenium in Xvfb? - Stack Overflow
